# LibreOffice commandline convert with template

Tags: html, templates, command-line, libreoffice, odt

I have a little app to convert a HTML file to ODT, with the soffice command line. I want to add a template to conversion.

**Is that possible?**

I tried with `-n template.ott` (from `man libreoffice`) but not work. The `template.ott` is a simple template with an image on the header.

Answer (score 1):

**No** according to the help it is not possible.

```
libreoffice --help
LibreOffice 4.2.7.2 420m0(Build:2)

Usage: soffice [options] [documents...]

Options:
--minimized    keep startup bitmap minimized.
--invisible    no startup screen, no default document and no UI.
--norestore    suppress restart/restore after fatal errors.
--quickstart   starts the quickstart service
--nologo       don't show startup screen.
--nolockcheck  don't check for remote instances using the installation
--nodefault    don't start with an empty document
--headless     like invisible but no userinteraction at all.
--help/-h/-?   show this message and exit.
--version      display the version information.
--writer       create new text document.
--calc         create new spreadsheet document.
--draw         create new drawing.
--impress      create new presentation.
--base         create new database.
--math         create new formula.
--global       create new global document.
--web          create new HTML document.
-o             open documents regardless whether they are templates or not.
-n             always open documents as new files (use as template).

--display <display>
      Specify X-Display to use in Unix/X11 versions.
-p <documents...>
      print the specified documents on the default printer.
--pt <printer> <documents...>
      print the specified documents on the specified printer.
--view <documents...>
      open the specified documents in viewer-(readonly-)mode.
--show <presentation>
      open the specified presentation and start it immediately
--accept=<accept-string>
      Specify an UNO connect-string to create an UNO acceptor through which
      other programs can connect to access the API
--unaccept=<accept-string>
      Close an acceptor that was created with --accept=<accept-string>
      Use --unnaccept=all to close all open acceptors
--infilter=<filter>
      Force an input filter type if possible
      Eg. --infilter="Calc Office Open XML"
--convert-to output_file_extension[:output_filter_name] [--outdir output_dir] files
      Batch convert files.
      If --outdir is not specified then current working dir is used as output_dir.
      Eg. --convert-to pdf *.doc
          --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /home/user *.doc
--print-to-file [-printer-name printer_name] [--outdir output_dir] files
      Batch print files to file.
      If --outdir is not specified then current working dir is used as output_dir.
      Eg. --print-to-file *.doc
          --print-to-file --printer-name nasty_lowres_printer --outdir /home/user *.doc
--pidfile file
      Store soffice.bin pid to file.

Remaining arguments will be treated as filenames or URLs of documents to open.
```